# GET works while POST fails to RESTlet call

Tags: c#, web-services, netsuite

I have two calls to RESTlet NetSuite web service from C# application that post data - GET and POST.

GET works fine - I receive success answer. This is how it looks on Fiddler:

```
https://some.netsuite.uri&deploy=1&my_id=123&my_a_id=Test66&param=4&amount=66 HTTP/1.1
Authorization: NLAuth nlauth_account=1234567_SB9, nlauth_email=xx@xx.com, nlauth_signature=Pass123456, nlauth_role=3
Accept: application/json
Host: rest.eu1.netsuite.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

Returns

```
success
```

But I suppose it is more correct to use POST. But it fails:

```
POST https://some.netsuite.uri&deploy=1 HTTP/1.1
Authorization: NLAuth nlauth_account=1234567_SB9, nlauth_email=xx@xx.com, nlauth_signature=Pass123456, nlauth_role=3
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host: some.netsuite.uri
Cookie: JSESSIONID=**************************************; lastUser=1234567_SB9_1282_3; NS_ROUTING_VERSION=LAGGING; NS_VER=2017.1.0
Content-Length: 51
Expect: 100-continue
Connection: Keep-Alive

my_id=123&my_a_id=Test66&param=4&amount=66
```

Returns HTML:

```
An unexpected error has occurred. Please click here to notify support and provide your contact information.
```

What might be wrong?

UPD

I have updated POST with JSON data:

```
POST https://some.netsuite.uri&deploy=1 HTTP/1.1
Authorization: NLAuth nlauth_account=XXXXX, nlauth_email=XXXXX, nlauth_signature=XXXXX, nlauth_role=3
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Host: rest.eu1.netsuite.com
Cookie: JSESSIONID=**************************************; lastUser=1234567_SB9_1282_3; NS_ROUTING_VERSION=LAGGING; NS_VER=2017.1.0
Content-Length: 69
Expect: 100-continue

{"my_id":"975","my_a_id":"Test66","param":"4","amount":"66"}
```

And got answer:

```
    HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    Date: Sat, 03 Jun 2017 06:21:46 GMT
    Server: Apache
    Cache-Control: No-Cache
    Pragma: No-Cache
    Content-Length: 41
    Expires: 0
    Edge-Control: no-store
    X-N-OperationId: 486c2d20-099d-446b-9788-4816db59a1fd
    Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=64.............................
; path=/
    NS_RTIMER_COMPOSITE: 1688996695:706172746E6572733030312E70726F642E6475622E6E65746C65646765722E636F6D:80
    P3P: CP="CAO PSAa OUR BUS PUR"
    Vary: User-Agent
    Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8

    org.mozilla.javascript.Undefined@54b896b0
```

From one side I suppose `HTTP/1.1 200 OK` means server has accepted data. But what means `org.mozilla.javascript.Undefined@54b896b0` ?

Comment: At first glance your URL looks incorrect:


https://some.netsuite.uri&deploy=1

should be

https://some.netsuite.uri?deploy=1

Comment: It looks like you have pasted your actual credentials - make sure to change your password asap!

Answer (score 3):

Your request Content Type is wrong `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. Restlets only support `application/json`. Make sure that you are sending a valid JSON in your request body:

```
{
    "my_id": 123,
    "my_a_id": "Test66",
    "param": 4,
    "amount": 66
}
```